# Spring MVC with ajax -- required long parameter 'id' is not present

Tags: ajax, spring-mvc

Note that this question is different from #19619088 because I am trying to pass plain text.

Here is Java code:

```
public @ResponseBody
String decertifyAll(
    @RequestParam(value="reason",required=false) String reason,
    @RequestParam("id") long id,
    final HttpServletRequest request) {
...
```

Here is my ajax:

```
$.ajax({
    url: '/dothing',
    data: {
        id: id,
        reason: reason
    },
    processData: false,
    contentType: false,
    dataType: 'text',
    type: 'POST',
  }).done(saveDone)
    .fail(saveFail)
    ;
```

In firebug, this is captured:

```
Source
{"id":"1492811","reason":"text"}
```

But, I still get the error:

```
 Required long parameter 'id' is not present
```

The weird thing is, this actually worked fine and then suddenly stopped working. I have no idea why.

My question is: What do I need to change so that I can pass this data correctly, and why is it failing to find the data that I am passing and that is making it into the post request?

I don't want to wrap this all up in some other object, but I will if needed.

Comment: Have you got `@RequestMapping(value="/dothing", method=RequestMethod.POST)`? And why are you using `processData=false`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This was solved by removing some of the optional parameters that I have in my AJAX call:

```
$.ajax({
    url: '/dothing',
    data: {
        id: id,
        reason: reason
    },
    type: 'POST',
  }).done(saveDone)
    .fail(saveFail)
    ;
```

I'm guessing that beerbajay's comment was correct that processData:false was the cause.